# Wifiphisher is not starting

Tags: python

When I run wifiphisher (both with jamming on and nojamming) I receive this error. I'm still fairly new to Ubuntu, and I don't have any idea how to fix it.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wifiphisher", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('wifiphisher==1.3', 'console_scripts', 'wifiphisher')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wifiphisher-1.3-py2.7.egg/wifiphisher/pywifiphisher.py", line 18, in <module>
    import wifiphisher.common.deauth as deauth
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wifiphisher-1.3-py2.7.egg/wifiphisher/common/deauth.py", line 10, in <module>
    import scapy.layers.dot11 as dot11
ImportError: No module named scapy.layers.dot11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"ImportError: No module named scapy.layers.dot11"` is telling you that wifiphiser requires a module called `"scapy.layers.dot11"`, and you do not have it.

Read all the documentation that came with `wifiphisher` - find out what additional packages are required.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't exactly realize that I had to install that package. Now I know for the future, and it solved my problem.